# Azure Data studio - connection to server in the same network - Error: The received certificate has expired

Tags: sql-server-2016, connections, certificate, azure-data-studio

I am trying to connect to SQL server on my network with Azure Data Studio, and I am getting error:

*A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The received certificate has expired.)*

Connection works through SSMS and I am db_datareader on that server.

Azure Data Studio version is 1.30.0

The details of the error:

*Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The received certificate has expired.)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090328): The received certificate has expired.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(PacketHandle packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec, FeatureExtension requestedFeatures, SessionData recoverySessionData, Nullable 1 fedAuthFeatureExtensionData)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Login(ServerInfo server, TimeoutTimer timeout, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass47_0.b__0(Task 1 _)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser\ReliableConnection\ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 314
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in D:\a\1\s\src\Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer\Connection\ConnectionService.cs:line 555
ClientConnectionId:
Error Number:-2146893016,State:0,Class:20*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue -- got around it by setting "Trust server certificate" to "True" in "Advanced Properties" of "Connection".

Comment: Wow! Thanks mate! That solved the problem.
Sooo simple yet it didn't cross my mind...